# Unity2d Placing Objects Adjacently

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to place a stack of boxes on top of each other based on the height of the previous box.

**The box's heights are dynamic.**

```
foreach( cBox box in currentLevel.mMiddleRack.BoxWeightList)
         {
             box.mBoxImage = (GameObject) Instantiate(boxTemplate);
             box.setBoxPosition(firstBoxPostion.x, firstBoxPostion.y, firstBoxPostion.z);
             firstBoxPostion.y += box.mBoxImage.transform.localScale.y;
             firstBoxPostion.z -= 1.0f;

             box.shapeBox();
         }
```

The Result
[image]

Comment: are the instantiated boxes identical in heights? if not, you need to store the previously instantiated box's localscale and use it when placing the new, different-sized box.

Comment: The OP stated "The box's heights are dynamic."; therefore, the boxes can be different sizes.  Localscale provides proportions to the original size (scaling factor), which does not give units in world space.  What is needed to access the bounds of an object in world space is to access its collider or determine this from its mesh.

Comment: Box's size being dynamic doesn't necessarily imply their sizes are uniform. They can still be dynamic -- changing size in run time -- and have different sizes, thus OP might need to check the previous box size during instantiation in the loop.

Comment: @JaysonAsh I think we just stated the same thing in three different sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform.localscale doesn't provide the size of the object, unless the object coincidentally happens to have the same scale as its size (primitive object, which has a size of (1,1,1)).

Try getting the size of the object by using [BoxCollider](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider.html) or, if using 2D physics, [BoxCollider2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html).  Use the size variable to help calculate the position of the boxes.

Comment: *Transform.localscale doesn't provide the size of the object, unless the object coincidentally happens to have the same scale as its size.* 
This is wrong man.

[Transform.localScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/class-Transform.html) : " Value “1” is the original size (size at which the object was imported)."

Comment: How is this wrong?  Transform.localScale is a proportion to the original size, which disregards unit space.  What is needed in this problem is units, not arbitrary scaling factors.

Comment: There seems to be confusion about what localscale actually represents.  An object with a world size of 10 units wide, 5 units long, and 4 units tall can have a localscale of 1.  This happens with the original mesh being 10 wide, 5 long, and 4 tall.

Comment: I might be wrong, I automatically assumed primitive objects and downvoted. If you can edit your question, I can upvote it.

Comment: Yeah, primitive objects are what I was hinting at that have the coincidental property of sharing the same size as the scale.  I edited my answer to be more explicit about this.  Thanks!

Comment: boxCollider did work. But my original intent was to avoid colliders. Because they are not being used for anything else just a single calculation.

Comment: Have a look at this link, it should help to avoid using boxcolliders and instead access the Renderer component to obtain the bounds (which contains the extents): http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html